# How to disable Camera And Screen Share for all applications (globally) in mac Using MDM?

Tags: macos

We know that using MDM we can handle **Privacy Preferences Policy Control** in mac.

> I am able to disable **Screen Sharing** and **Camera feature** for the
> Particular Application.

Is there any way by which we can disable this globally for all applications?

[Payload Example](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mdm/mdm9ddb7e0b5/1/web/1)

[Device Management Profile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/privacypreferencespolicycontrol/services/identity)

[PrivacyPreferencesPolicyControl.Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/privacypreferencespolicycontrol/services)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394075/how-to-disable-camera-and-screen-share-for-all-applications-globally-in-mac-us

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree with your point but I am looking for answer of this.
I get a comment from the developers to ask at superuser you might get answer here that's why I asked here.